# PyQt4: Open and Properly Destroy a QMainWindow from another one

Tags: python, pyqt4, qmainwindow

I have a problem with my project. In it I have a main form, that has eight huge buttons to call other forms. Basically I created the ui files with Qt Designer and used `pyuic4 [ui_file] -o [py_file]` method to create forms, and in a `main.py` I'm importing them all.

Here are parts of the code:

```
from myraflib import myEnv
from myraflib import myFit

import sys
import sip
for cl in ('QString', 'QVariant'):
    sip.setapi(cl, 2)

from uis.myraf import Ui_MainWindow
from uis.calibration import Ui_MainWindowCali
from uis.align import Ui_MainWindowAlign
from uis.photometry import Ui_MainWindowPhoto
from uis.graph import Ui_MainWindowGraph
from uis.editor import Ui_MainWindowEdit
from uis.scheduler import Ui_MainWindowSche
from uis.settings import Ui_MainWindowSett
from uis.help import Ui_MainWindowHelp
from uis.error import Ui_MainWindowErr

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import gui as g
import functions as f

from fPlot import *


class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, verb=True):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.verb = verb
        self.ggui = g.Gui(verb=self.verb)
        self.meetc = myEnv.etc(verb=self.verb)

        self.child = {"calib": None, "align": None, "photo": None,
            "graph": None, "editor": None, "sched": None, "setti": None,
            "help": None}

        ...

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("calib"))

        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("align"))

        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("photo"))

        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("graph"))

        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("editor"))

        self.ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("sched"))

        self.ui.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("setti"))

        self.ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_form("help"))

        self.ui.actionQuit.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)

    #Here my best friend. The problem guy is here
    def show_form(self, frm):
        try:
            forms = {"calib": MyFormCali(self), "align": MyFormAli(self),
                 "photo": MyFormPho(self), "graph": MyFormGra(self),
                 "editor": MyFormEdi(self), "sched": MyFormSch(self),
                 "setti": MyFormSet(self), "help": MyFormHel(self)}
            if self.child[frm] is None:
                self.child[frm] = forms[frm]
            self.child[frm].show()
        except Exception as e:
            self.meetc.print_if(e)

    ...

    def closeEvent(self, evnt):
        for i in self.child:
            if not self.child[i] is None:
                self.child[i].close()


class MyFormCali(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindowCali):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, verb=True):
        super(MyFormCali, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindowCali()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.verb = verb
        self.ggui = g.Gui(verb=self.verb)
        self.meetc = myEnv.etc(verb=self.verb)
        self.mefo = myEnv.file_operation(verb=self.verb)
        self.mffo = myFit.fits_operation(verb=self.verb)
        self.mfho = myFit.header_operation(verb=self.verb)
        self.mfst = myFit.statistics_operation(verb=self.verb)
        self.fset = f.settings(verb=self.verb)

        ...

        self.child = {"error": None}

        ...

        self.ui.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(lambda:
            self.add_files(self.ui.listWidget_5))
        self.ui.pushButton_13.clicked.connect(lambda:
            self.add_files(self.ui.listWidget_6))
        self.ui.pushButton_15.clicked.connect(lambda:
            self.add_files(self.ui.listWidget_7))
        self.ui.pushButton_17.clicked.connect(lambda:
            self.add_files(self.ui.listWidget_8))

        ...

        self.info_update()

    ...

    def show_stats(self, list_dev):
        file_name = self.ggui.get_current_item_from_list(list_dev)

        ...

    def info_update(self):
        cda = 0

        ...

    def add_files(self, list_widget):
        files = self.ggui.get_file_list(self)
        if files[0]:
            self.ggui.set_values_to_list(self, list_widget, files[1])
        else:
            self.ggui.show_dialog(self, "info",
                "File Problem", "No file selected!")

        self.info_update()

    def closeEvent(self, evnt):
        for i in self.child:
            if not self.child[i] is None:
                self.child[i].close()
```

Well, I could share the whole project, but the general idea is that there are at least nine forms, and one of them is the main form which is named `MyForm`, and the others are `MyFormCali`, `MyFormAli`, `MyFormPho`, and so on. The main form is calling the others with the `show()` method.

The problems are:

1. Within the `show_form()` method I created in the `MyForm` class, all forms are declared in a dictionary type variable called `forms`. When it happens, actually all forms are loaded but none shown. I can see all of the `__init__` methods are called and there's no form visible. I tried to write a long `if` statement, but then I was able to open the same form more than once.
2. When I close a window it won't close properly. I mean I can still see the changes happened for forms after a close and re-open process. For example, I'm adding some values to `QListWidget`'s and after a reopen I can still see the values.

Long story short, I need a better way to open/destroy a `QMainWindow` from another one.

Comment: it seems you only hide windows so you have to (on your own) clear fields after you reopen it (or rather after unhide). Normally you create new instance and you get empty fields. In dict you can keep class names `MyFormAli` instead of instances `MyFormAli(self)` and open `self.child[frm](self).show()` to get new instance.

Comment: Wow. The first problem solved. :)
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can try to add the `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on your main window : `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)`